# When and how to Use "return this" in Java

Tags: java, return, this

I'm developing a simple java project to help me master the language and was researching on *method chaining* when I came across the `return this` statement.  I'm not quite sure of its use cases apart from method chaining and what it means exactly to `return this`. Its documentation was obviously not written for newbies. Could someone help make it clearer?

Comment: It returns a value, just like any other `return` statement.  The value happens to be `this`.  What don't you understand?

Comment: In addition such is very common among diverse [`Build/er pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: `return this` is typically used with builder patterns: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html This lets you chain in a single statement multiple parameter settings where it'd be a multi-line statement typically calling individual setters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
return this;
```

returns the instance itself from the method.

Returning the instance is usually (but not always) used when implementing a [*fluent interface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), which allows code to look like this:

```
myObj.method1().method2().method3();
```

This in turn is very commonly used (but not *required*) when implementing the [*builder pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

`return this` simply means "return the reference of the *current* instance".